# MatLab - Compare uneven matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have one matrix of 24 coordinates in 2 columns (12x2):

matrix1:

1.1, 4.1

2.3, 4.8

9.1, 33.1

12.45, 45.67
etc...

I wish to compare this to over 100 other matrix's of ranging sizes for example some will consists of 10 coordinates some will consists of 15 some will even be 24. This is done in order to find matches

To compare them i have found the pdist of elements in the matrix's and then use a tolerance so they do not have to be exact in order to match then use 'mode' to find majority in order to decide if match or not.

so this works great for matrix's of the same size.... but not the others, so i decided to replace blank spaces in matrix's that do not equal the max possible matrix with 0 forcing them all to be same size. this allowed matching but because of pdist created distances which i did not want to use.

my comparison code:

Results = (array >= matrix1 * 0.1 & array < matrix1 * 1.5);

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

SHORT VERSION

compare two uneven matrices

my code will only allow me to compare matrixs of the same size any advice?

Results = (array >= matrix1 * 0.1 & array < matrix1 * 1.5);

Comment: No offense, but this is too verbose, so it's unclear where you are stuck. If you give a simple (and short) example of what you have and what you want, it'll be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: If performance is not an issue, the easiest solution may be to pad with `NaN` instead of zero.

Comment: Let me see if I have this right: you have a 12x2 matrix, and you want to compare that to other matrices which are NxM. You determine whether a matrix matches by checking to see how many of its elements appear in both matrices (within some tollerance), and then threshold this value. Is that an accurate summary?

Comment: nan is a good idea but would that mean importing all arrays in matrix2 into new arrays so nans can be set?

Comment: no i check by creating pdist of the elements in each array

Comment: Ok, so you have a 12x2 matrix, A, which you take the pdist of, giving you a 1x276 vector of pairwise distances. And you also have an MxN matrix, B, which you do the same to giving you an M*(M-1)/2 vector of pairwise distances, and then you compare those two sets of pairwise distances?

Comment: @Tom, after checking your other questions I think I might be a bit closer this time: do you mean you use pdist2(A,B) and then count the number of elements smaller than your threshold?

Comment: apology's for my confusing text let me elaborate pdist(x) creates distances between elements inside each matrix (?) then using the code provided above i threshold and match. the threshold should be a range so from the lowest value to the highest anything between that range will result in a match.

Answer (score 0):

I'go this way, but I don't know if it will fulfill your requirements:

```
array = randi(100,24,2); % starting matrix
matrix = randi(100,13,2); % comparative matrix
matrix1 = padarray(matrix,size(array) - size(matrix),'post'); % pad comparative matrix with zeros

results = (array >= matrix1 * 0.1 & array < matrix1 * 1.5);
```

Comment: can i pad with nan? that works but i it then useing the 0s in the mathcing process giving false results

Comment: I think you can then call this

`matrix1(matrix1 == 0) = NaN`.